# Pandas for loop to copy columns to separate dataframe, rename df accordingly

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I'm trying to take a dataframe, iterate over each column starting with the 2nd and copy that first constant column + next ones one by one to new dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year':[2001 ,2002, 2003, 2004, 2005], 'a': [1,2, 3, 4, 5], 'b': [10,20, 30, 40, 50], 'c': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4,0.5]})
df
```

To get a result similar to what this outputs, but i need it to loop since I can have up to 40 columns to run logic on.

```
df_a=pd.DataFrame()
df_a=df[['Year', 'a']].copy()
df_b=df[['Year', 'b']].copy()
df_c=df[['Year', 'c']].copy()
print(df_a)
print(df_b)
print(df_c)
```

It would also be nice if I know how to name the df_['name of column it's copying']. Thank you so much and sorry if it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest splitting it through a dict comprehension, then you'll have a dictionary of your separate dataframes. For example:

```
dict_of_frames = {f'df_{col}':df[['Year', col]] for col in df.columns[1:]}
```

Gives you a dictionary of `df_a`, `df_b` and `df_c`, which you can access as you would any other dictionary:

```
>>> dict_of_frames['df_a']
   Year  a
0  2001  1
1  2002  2
2  2003  3
3  2004  4
4  2005  5

>>> dict_of_frames['df_b']
   Year   b
0  2001  10
1  2002  20
2  2003  30
3  2004  40
4  2005  50
```

Comment: Thank  you so much @sacul! One more Q, so if I needed to iterate through these frames should I do: for i in range (1, len(df.columns[4:]):
finaldf={dict_of_frames['df_{col}'] for col in df.columns[4:]} ???

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but I would iterate through by saying: `for df in dict_of_frames.keys(): dict_of_frames[df] ...`

Comment: Thank you @sacul - you guys rock! Hail to the stack overflow community!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a dictionary of dataframes like below with column name as key and subdataframe as value.

```
df = df.set_index('Year')
dict_ = {col: df[[col]].reset_index() for col in df.columns}
```

You can simply use column name to access the dictionary and get the corresponding dataframe.

```
dict_['a']
```

Output:

```
    Year    a
0   2001    1
1   2002    2
2   2003    3
3   2004    4
4   2005    5
```

You can iterate over the `dict_` by:

```
for col, df in dict_.items():
    print("-"*40) #just for separation
    print(df) #or print(dict_[col])
```

Output:

```
----------------------------------------
   Year  a
0  2001  1
1  2002  2
2  2003  3
3  2004  4
4  2005  5
----------------------------------------
   Year   b
0  2001  10
1  2002  20
2  2003  30
3  2004  40
4  2005  50
----------------------------------------
   Year    c
0  2001  0.1
1  2002  0.2
2  2003  0.3
3  2004  0.4
4  2005  0.5
```

Comment: Once again, we end up at the same basic answer!

Comment: You posted x seconds before me. I guess, I should be fast. @sacul. :P

Comment: Thank you! @harvpan ! Sorry I asked this one above to, so if I needed to iterate through these frames should I do: for i in range (1, len(df.columns[4:]): finaldf={dict_of_frames['df_{col}'] for col in df.columns[4:]} ???

Comment: @MarinaGoldylocks See the edit. I hope that clears how you ca iterate through the `dict_` . Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you, @harvpan - super helpful! Everything's working!

Comment: @MarinaGoldylocks consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) the answer, if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You don't *need* to create a dictionary to copy and access the data you require. You can simply copy your dataframe (deep copy if you have mutable elements) and then use indexing to access a particular series:

```
dfs = df.set_index('Year').copy()

print(dfs['a'])

Year
2001    1
2002    2
2003    3
2004    4
2005    5
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

You can iterate over your columns via [`pd.DataFrame.iteritems`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iteritems.html):

```
for key, series in dfs.iteritems():
    print(key, series)
```

Yes, this gives series, but they can easily be converted to dataframes via `series.reset_index()` or `series.to_frame()`.

Comment: Thank you, @jpp - that's a nice alternative!